# Autohotkey: Toggle caps lock on/off on activating certain windows

Tags: autohotkey

I want to write a script that will turn on caps lock when I activate a window containing particular keyword in its title(like SQL). I also want the caps lock to be turned off when I switch to a window whose title does not contain any of the keywords that I have specified.

How can I do it? I have considered `#Persistent` with a timer to periodically check active window. But, I think there should be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check answers at: http://www.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/comments/1qjf83/force_specific_program_to_use_caps/. Especially G33kDude's answer. It's a clever and efficient solution: check of current window is binded only to windows activation.

=======================

Edit: Code inserted below.
Please note that it's not a complete solution, you'll need to make some edits for your needs. Not a big ones, though.

```
#Persistent ; Don't close when the auto-execute ends

SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ; Partial title matching
WinGet, myHwnd, ID, Notepad ; Get the handle to the your window

; Listen for activation messages to all windows
DllCall("CoInitialize", "uint", 0)
if (!hWinEventHook := DllCall("SetWinEventHook", "uint", 0x3, "uint",     0x3, "uint", 0, "uint", RegisterCallback("HookProc"), "uint", 0, "uint", 0,     "uint", 0))
{
    MsgBox, Error creating shell hook
    Exitapp
}

;MsgBox, Hook made
;DllCall("UnhookWinEvent", "uint", hWinEventHook) ; Remove the     message listening hook
return

; Handle the messages we hooked on to
HookProc(hWinEventHook, event, hwnd, idObject, idChild,     dwEventThread, dwmsEventTime)
{
    global myHwnd
    static lastHwnd
    WinGetTitle, title, ahk_id %hwnd%

    if (hwnd == myHwnd) ; If our window was just activated
    {
        tooltip, Gained focus
    }
    else if (lastHwnd == myHwnd) ; If our window was just     deactivated
    {
        tooltip, Lost focus
    }

    lastHwnd := hwnd
}
```

Comment: Some more information would be great in case of a broken link ;-)

Comment: Not working for me...Autohotkey running as admin..Put a msgbox with tooltip...does not show up...

Comment: Do you have Notepad already running when you start the script?

Comment: I tried both things, notepad previously running and not running. Probably some problem on my side. I got it to work with Elliot's answer...Thanks though..

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this without using `SetTimer`, the best way would be to use [context-sensitive](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/commands/_If.htm) hotkeys.  For Example:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

#If WinActive("SQL") or WinActive("Notepad")
    a::A
    b::B
    c::C
    d::D
    e::E
    ;; etc.
```

You could also use the `WinActive` function with [Window Groups](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GroupAdd.htm) instead of the title if you wanted to avoid a very long `#If` line.

**EDIT: Case-Insensitive Example**

```
SetTitleMatchMode, Regex

GroupAdd, Editor, (?i).*sql ; Regular expression for window title
GroupAdd, Editor, (?i).*ahk

#IfWinActive ahk_group Editor
    a::A
    b::B
    c::C
    d::D
    e::E
    ;; etc.
```

Comment: Thanks. I dont know why but this does not work when I am editing sql file in Notepad++. I know its case sensitive so I included both upper and lower case SQL and I checked the window title with Window Spy and it does contain sql...Any idea why?

Comment: And how can I make it case insensitive?

Comment: Be sure AutoHotkey.exe is running as an Administrator.  Sometimes this is the cause of not seeing a window title.  I've edited my answer to include a case-insensitive example.

Comment: It still does not work...I also tried adding another .* to "sql" at the end...I tried running as Admin as well...
Anyways, your script seems fine... I'll do some more testing at my end

Comment: I cant get it to work...
Apparently WinActive does not match partial title irrespective of SetTitleMatchMode

Comment: Yep, sounds like something specific to your machine.  The code itself is sound.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with version? I am running latest unicode x64 version of autohotkey

Comment: I got it to work. Putting the whole thing at start of the script worked. And no, I don't have any un-'returned' hotkeys because simple hotkeys put at the end of script did work....Thanks

Comment: When using `#If` conditionals, you must use another closing `#If` at the end to avoid affecting other hotkeys. That's what it sounds like was happening. Glad you got it to work.

Comment: Yes I have done it. No hard feelings, I marked another answer as accepted because I think its more efficient. You solution sometimes introduces some lag between key press and character typed on screen. Your solution works perfectly fine though. I wish I could mark both answers accepted...

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a Autoit in your tag, here is how it is done easy in autoit.

```
Opt("SendCapslockMode", 0)

While 1

    Sleep(200)
    $title = WinGetTitle("", ""); will get the title of the active window

    If StringInStr($title, "sql") Then
        Send("{CAPSLOCK ON}")
    Else
        Send("{CAPSLOCK OFF}")
    EndIf

WEnd
```

Comment: Does this work with autohotkey? I have lots of scripts in there so I am kinda reluctant on switching to AutoIt......i added the tag because they are very similar...

Comment: @tumchaaditya Unfortunately no. It will only work with autoit.

Answer (score 1):

[Milos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2097265/milos)' answer is quite straight forward, but it misses a vital point. You need to set `SendCapslockMode` to `0`. Else the effect of the `Send` command will be useless, because after the command the original state will be restored.

The next thing is, you don't need to use an infinite loop with a `Sleep` which will execute the complete loop body every few milliseconds, but you can wait for the active window to not be active any more, which is less CPU intensive. So a fully working solution in AutoIt is:

```
Opt("SendCapslockMode", 0)

While True
   $win = WinGetHandle("[ACTIVE]")

   If StringInStr(WinGetTitle($win), "sql") Then
      Send("{CAPSLOCK ON}")
   Else
      Send("{CAPSLOCK OFF}")
   EndIf

   WinWaitNotActive($win)
WEnd
```

Comment: Hehe, just copy it ;-)
Did you test your code whether it was working before? It should have been a problem.

Comment: No. Just wrote it from scratch :D

Comment: I meant the "suggestion" ;-) You just placed it into your answer like it had always been there.^^

Answer (score 0):

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.


; This script solves the problem of forgetting to turn on or off the capslock when using specific programs
; I for one ALWAYS use capital letters when typing things in CAD. My problem was when switching to another
; program, usually e-mail, I'd start typing and then have to erase it. Problem solved!

; The beauty of this script is that you don't lose the ability to manually turn the capslock on or off 
; My first few interations of this script would turn it on when in the CAD window but then
; I'd never be able to turn it on wihtout it being forced off again.


Loop    {

state := GetKeyState("Capslock", "T")        ; check toggle state, save in variable 'state'

if state = 0
    status = Off                ; this block converts the 1 or 0 of variable 'state'
if state = 1                    ; into the word ON or OFF and stores it in variable 'status'
    status = On


Beginsub:

WinGetTitle, Title, A                ; retreive current window title, store in Title


if title contains AutoCAD 2012            ; if title contains "AutoCAD" turn on capslock
                        ; then go back to the BeginSub subroutine and see if the title 
{    SetCapsLockState, on            ; still matches "AutoCAD 2012" if it does not...\/\/\/
    goto, BeginSub
            }

SetCapsLockState, %status%            ; ...Put caps lock back to the state it was when we started.

                        ; 'SetCapsLockState'  doesn't recognize a 1/0 variable
                        ; therefore the use of 'status' and ON/OFF words

Sleep, 1000                    ; only check every second


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Persistent

SetTitleMatchMode, 2   ; use RegEx for finer control

Loop
{
    WinWaitActive, Notepad
    {
        WinGet, opVar, ID
        SetCapsLockState, On
    }

    WinWaitNotActive, ahk_id %opVar%
        SetCapsLockState, Off
}
```